# Plotly: How to reverse axes?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

I want to reverse the y-axis of the graph I've obtained for all the over-plots using plotly.graph_objects. I know reversing of the axis can be done using plotly.express. But I would like to know how to reverse the axis using `plotly.graph_objects`:

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
fig['layout']['yaxis']['autorange'] = "reversed"
```

and:

```
fig['layout']['xaxis']['autorange'] = "reversed"
```

**Plot - default axis:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0, 5, 200)
y = np.sin(t)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=t, y=y, mode='markers'))

fig.show()
```

**Plot - reversed x axis:**

[image]

**Plot - reversed y axis:**

[image]

**Code - reversed axes:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0, 5, 200)
y = np.sin(t)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=t, y=y, mode='markers'))
fig['layout']['xaxis']['autorange'] = "reversed"
fig['layout']['yaxis']['autorange'] = "reversed"

fig.show()
```

Comment: Awesome, this works for a particular subplot as well. Whereas ```fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")``` given in plotly documentation reverses the y axis for all the subplots in a row

Comment: Update to 2023, this was the only solution that actually worked.

Answer (score 6):

```
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed", row=2, col=1)
```

Also works for subplots without changing the order for other plots

Comment: As a comment to this answer, when trying this an error is thrown that "row" is not recognized. Was there another setup step for this to work? Perhaps a version that has changed? It doesn't work now.

Comment: the row and col is for illustrating use when using in a subplot. Leave out altogether if using a single graph.